# Do concepts alleviate the need of defining classes in header files?

Tags: c++, c++20

Bjarne Stroustrup has mentioned the disadvantage of having to define templates in header files multiple times. 
Example: https://youtu.be/HddFGPTAmtU

My question is now, if this is now solved by the new concepts feature of C++ in C++20?

I cannot really find anything regarding that and Bjarne did also not say anything about that anymore, afaik.

Comment: How did you make the logical leap from concepts to alleviating the need to have templates in headers? Do you have an example in mind? Otherwise this is just a random guess.

Comment: I have seen two talks about concepts from Bjarne Stroustrupp and in both talks this specific disadvantage is mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concepts itself doesn't eliminate this, but C++ Modules will. C++ Modules are separate from concepts: you can use modules without using concepts. But given that Concepts encourage the creation of generic code, Modules will be a much needed addition.

You'll be able to use Modules side-by-side with `#include`: you can use one, the other, or both as fits your needs. Modules will speed up the compilation of code significantly, and with modules you'll be able to put templates (and concepts) in a cpp file without even having a header file.

Answer (score 1):

Concepts are about constraining templates and template-related entities. Concepts do not, and has never tried to, address the restriction on having to define templates in header files.

Modules, on the other hand, *does* try to address that issue. Not by letting you define templates in source files, but by adding a totally new encapsulation layer to the language and hopefully reducing compile times as a result. But while Concepts have already been added to the working draft for C++20, Modules has not been. It's looking like it could make C++20, but it is not yet clear if it will or not. We'll see.